# C++ - Proper way of using std::vector & related memory management

Tags: c++, memory-management, stdvector

Hy, I would like to ask a question that puzzles me.

I've a class like this:

```
class A { 

private:
std::vector<Object*>* my_array_;

...

public
std::vector<Object*>& my_array(); // getter
void my_array(const std::vector<Object*>& other_array); // setter
};
```

I wanted to ask you, based on your experience, what is the correct way of implementing the setter and getter in a (possible) SAFE manner.

The first solution came to my mind is the following.

First, when I do implement the setter, I should:
A) check the input is not a referring to the data structure I already hold;
B) release the memory of ALL objects pointed by my_array_
C) copy each object pointed by other_array and add its copy to my_array_
D) finally end the function.

The getter may produce a copy of the inner array, just in case.

The questions are many:
- is this strategy overkilling?
- does it really avoid problems? 
- somebody really uses it or are there better approaches?

I've tried to look for the answer to this question, but found nothing so particularly focused on this problem.

---

That of using smart pointers is a very good answer, i thank you both.. it seems I can not give "useful answer" to more than one so I apologize in advance. :-)

From your answers however a new doubt has raised.
When i use a vector containing unique_ptr to objects, I will have to define a deep copy constructor. Is there a better way than using an iterator to copy each element in the vector of objects, given that now we are using smart pointers?

Comment: Why do you have pointers to `std::vector` in your objects?

Comment: I would go with "resilient to silent errors produced by misuses of the class". But it is a blurred concept, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd normally recommend not using a pointer to a vector as a member, but from your question it seems like it's shared between multiple instances.

That said, I'd go with:

```
class A { 
private:
   std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object> > > my_array_;

public
   std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object> > >  my_array(); // getter
   void my_array(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object> > >  other_array); // setter
};
```

No checks necessary, no memory management issues.

If the inner `Object`s are also shared, use a `std::shared_ptr` instead of the `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Out of interest, if A owns the structure, do you not think that the getter should return by reference and own with a unique_ptr? -- thus expressed the relationship more clearly. Just after an opinion if you have the time.

Comment: @111111 the thing is I don't think A owns the structure.

Comment: but if it did, would that be what you would do?

Comment: @111111 but yes, if `A` is the sole owner, it should use a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: +1 The only thing to be careful of with this approach is to make sure that `Object` can't hold a `std::shared_ptr` to the `std::vector` or there'll be a circle of references and the memory will never be freed.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore
I don't have any real reason for using Pointers.. indeed, I'm trying to build a parse tree. I've tried to maintain a certain degree of flexibility because I still don't know whether the same object can be put into different vectors or not.. Circular dependencies should not be there in any case.

I thank you for your advice, It seems clever enough, but I can't get how it solved my problem.. and what I'm supposed to do with std::shared_ptr and std::unique_ptr afterwards :-)

Comment: @user1753515 that's the magic of it - nothing. All is done automatically. Read into them.

Comment: uh oh.. thanks.. seems I've to rewrite the entire library lol

Comment: @user1753515 better now than later.

Comment: :-) ..just in case, is there any good reason why you did not use "pass by reference" nor "const" ?

Comment: @V'GerRobert because they're no longer needed. Passing a smart pointer by value is efficient, and passing by value makes the `const` useless.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overcomplicating things having *a pointer to* `std::vector` as data member; remember that C++ is not Java (C++ is more "value" based than "reference" based).

Unless there is a strong reason to use a pointer to a `std::vector` as data member, I'd just use a simple `std::vector` stored "by value".

Now, regarding the `Object*` pointers in the `vector`, you should ask yourself: are those **observing** pointers or are those **owning** pointers?

If the `vector` just *observes* the `Object`s (and they are owned by someone else, like an object pool allocator or something), you can use raw pointers (i.e. simple `Object*`). 
But if the vector has some ownership semantics on the `Object`s, you should use `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` *smart* pointers. If the vector is the *only owner* of `Object` instances, use `unique_ptr`; else, use `shared_ptr` (which uses a *reference counting* mechanism to manage object lifetimes).

```
class A 
{ 
public:
  // A vector which owns the pointed Objects
  typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>> ObjectArray;

  // Getter
  const ObjectArray& MyArray() const
  {
      return m_myArray
  }

  // Setter 
  // (new C++11 move semantics pattern: pass by value and move from the value)
  void MyArray(ObjectArray otherArray)
  {
      m_myArray = std::move(otherArray);
  }

private:
  ObjectArray m_myArray;
};
```